# Script shell echo result of command has unknown values

Tags: shell

I try to echo the result of a command. But my problem is that the result has strange values at the end and I can not delete them.

My result after the command is for example:

```
fnRead 

results to 12. Juni 13:32:18 2028 þ§
```

But I only need 12. Juni 13:32:18 2028 because I want to check the equivalence of two strings

My code that generates this output is a function:

```
fnRead() {
    echo $(cat /dev/rtc)
}
```

I tried to cut off the last strings but it will only remove numbers from the year.

Im working with shell scripts by the way.

Comment: Note that simply `cat /dev/rtc` would do the job; there's no need for the command substitution and `echo`.

Comment: sry forgot to mention that the cat /dev/rtc is inside a function. I use $(cat /dev/rtc) to execute the command and getting the result als an echo

Comment: OK; working out context can be tricky.  It's not unreasonable to need `var=$(cat /dev/rtc)` — or, in Bash, `var=$(</dev/rtc)` — to assign to a variable for later use and then `echo` for debugging/checking purposes.  Separately, haven't they fixed things like this by the year 2028?  I was hoping things would have improved by then.  And thank you for dropping back to chat with us.  Does this mean that SO doesn't exist still in 2028?

Comment: Very funny ;) I can rewrite this date. This was only an example for my format of date. I am writing tests in shell script. Therefore it is important to know which date was written into the chip

Answer (score 2):

According to documentation, you need to use [hwclock](http://linux.die.net/man/8/hwclock) to read/write from /dev/rtc. You are seeing a raw output of this interface.

See also: http://linux.die.net/man/4/rtc

Comment: there are several ways to get the time. I need to use both commands. hwclock which uses ioctl and cat /dev/rtc which uses rtc_read function. This is because I wrote my own rtc driver.

Comment: Are you sure your RTC driver is doing what it is supposed to do?

Comment: Yes ;) Its for educational purpose only. I have to set a range of years which the chip can handle. So its possible for me to write time in the future